# How to parse XML using a condition?

Tags: c#, xml

The `articleABS()` method output’s the following XML.

`Conflict <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <?xml-stylesheet href="#####" type="text/xsl"?> <?xml-stylesheet href="####" type="text/css"?> <status><code>409</code><message>content.article.required.title null</message></status>`

I have created `createURL()` method, which should read the output from the `articleABS()` and extract the value from the `<code>` node.   I would like to use the value from the code to add some conditions.

```
  public string createURL()
    {
        string uri = "";

        var document = XDocument.Parse(articleABS());

        var code = document.Descendants("status").Single().Attribute("code").Value;

        if (code == "209")

        {
            articleCDO();
        }

        else 

        {

        var href = document.Descendants("link").Single().Attribute("title").Value;
        href = href.Replace("Article", "");
        string id = Regex.Match(href, @"\d+").Value;
        var result = (@"https://#####/article/" + id + "/sections");
        return uri = result.ToString();

        }

        return null;

    }
```

However, when I run the `createURL()` function, I keep getting the following 
error message.

Error message: `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

Code line: `var document = XDocument.Parse(articleABS());`

Please advise where I may be going wrong.  Thank you

Comment: An "XML" file that starts with the token `conflict` isn't XML.

Comment: What about `Conflict` word preceeding the xml data? Is it really there in your data?

Comment: Hi, Yes the xml includes the 'conflict' in the beginning.  Is it possible to bypass this.  the response from the `articleabs` only output's the `conflict` when the status code is equal to `209` otherwise the XML starts with correct syntax.  Thank you for any further advice.

Comment: Better to encode the information about the conflict into the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the word "Conflict" is at the beginning of you XML data. You would need to remove that before trying to parse the string as XML.

You could do:

```
string currentXml = articleABS();
string fixedXml = currentXml.Substring(currentXml.IndexOf("<"));

var document = XDocument.Parse(fixedXml);
```

Answer (score 3):

The XML begins with "Conflict ".  I don't know if that is a copy/paste error, but it would certainly cause parsing to fail.